# Looking up data with relational classes

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm developing an Android app that uses the Parse.com online database, and i'm having some difficulty wrapping my head around the relationship between classes.

I have the following classes defined: User (default), PrivateInfo, Relationships.

The relationships class is a many-to-many class between users (users stored as pointers), and the PrivateInfo class contains information specific to a user (stored as a pointer) to be accessed only by said user or users present in a relationship. For example, if user A is in a relationship with user B, then A should be able to access this privateInfo.

I have an activity where the private info from all users is to be shown. How can I build a query that will fetch the privateInfo from all users in a relationship with the current user? I've seen the usage of innerqueries in the documentation and I think that's what I should be using, but the usage of ParseObjects is making this confusing to me, since i'd have to work with PrivateInfo and Relationship ParseObjects, and not a User parseObject, which is what is being pointed by the privateInfo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look over the REST Api docs on ACL and on security..

Wnen you have User A in relation w/ B, you can UPD ACL READ on B's privateInfo , giving A read access.

Then you can just do an 'include=ClassPointedTO' on any query and the extra class ( private info will be inlined in response to flat query with the sensitive data ).

If u drop the relation you must keep info consistent by ALSO updating the ACL element to drop read on the dropped target of the dropped relation.

--EDIT--
So when the Privateinfo entry is created, you can grant ACL READ to the creating user if you want. Or you can grant ACL READ to a Role entry that the creating user is in. Or you can do both. You would also need ACL WRITE by the creating user.

After that, in any query by any user you would get the following on a direct Query on Privateinfo or on a query utilizing "?include=Privateinfo" ...

Users with READ ( either direct or via a Role which the user belongs to ) will have in the response those Privateinfo entries where they have READ.

Comment: I read the ACL article, and something wasn't very clear regarding queries. If I set the default ACU on the PrivateInfo object to only let the posters of the private info to be able to fetch it, only they can fetch it. But supose I add other users the the ACL. If those users perform a query on that class, they will only get the objects that they have read permissions on, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

An easily missed part of the documentation is the [Relations Guide](https://parse.com/docs/relations_guide) that explains the different types of relationships in much more detail than I can in an answer.

In regards to doing a query for "userA", looking to get all `PrivateInfo` objects that are for users that have a `Relationship` record that points to "userA":

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> relationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Relationship");
relationQuery.whereEqualTo("user", userA);

ParseQuery<ParseObject> privateInfoQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("PrivateInfo");
// find records where PrivateInfo.user == Relationship.relatedToUser
privateInfoQuery.whereMatchesKeyInQuery("user", "relatedToUser", relationQuery);
// if you also need the User so you can show info about them
privateInfoQuery.include("user");
```

This assumes your classes have the following columns:

- PrivateInfo

  - user : Pointer<_User>
- Relationship

  - user : Pointer<_User>
  - relatedToUser : Pointer<_User>

If you need to get Private info for reverse relationships too, it gets trickier. I can provide a sample OR query if needed.